# Passing a {sitename} parameter to MVC controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

How can I retrieve a **site-wide URL parameter** in a route without cluttering each controller action with a parameter? My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235118/asp-net-mvc-route-to-username), but I want to avoid the *ModelBinder* clutter. Ie. in *Global.asax.cs*:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{sitename}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { sitename = "", controller = "SomeController", action = "Index", id = "" }    );
```

So, instead of the following in SomeController class:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sitename)
{
    SiteClass site = GetSite(sitename);
    ...
    return View(site.GetViewModel());
}
```

I would rather have the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SiteClass site = CurrentSite; // where CurrentSite has already retrieved data based on unique URL sitename parameter.
    ...
    return View(site.GetViewModel());
}
```

Perhaps this can be achieved with controller-wide action filter? OnActionExecuting?

Comment: If the user is authenticated then why not use Membership.GetUser()

Comment: The parameter has nothing to do with authentication. Perhaps it would be clearer if I used {sitename} instead of {user} as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First add a route to Global.aspx.cs to pass a {sitename} parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Sites", // Route name
    "{sitename}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { sitename = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

### Then add the following simple code inside a base controller:

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    public string SiteName = "";

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        SiteName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["sitename"] as string;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

### And use in your derived controller:

```
public class HomeController: BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["SiteName"] = SiteName;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way, but it beats cracking open Application_BeginRequest.

Comment: In my implementation I don't use a string for SiteName. Instead I store the actual Site or Site data, which comes in handy for a multi-site application.

Comment: This answer is awesome, just saved me lots of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but why not simply do the following inside your controller action:

```
var sitename = RouteData.Values["sitename"] as string;
```

I don't understand why you would need to override OnActionExecuting (per @pate's answer) when you can retrieve the value when you need it.

There's also no need to create a base class and have everything derive from it. If you object to copying that line into every action method of every controller, why not create an extension method?