# How to handle site-wide querystring parameters in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to be able to process a querystring parameter throughout the site (like ?promo=38 for example).  I was trying the procedure specified here [Passing a {sitename} parameter to MVC controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237375/passing-a-sitename-parameter-to-mvc-controller-actions) but it wasn't working. My guess it's because according to http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/ querystring processing happens after the controller is instantiated.

So what would be a simple way to accomplish what I want? namely, being able to do something like setting a base controller property, or setting a session variable, from a querystring parameter anywhere in my site, without having to manually specify something in all the controller actions?

Comment: Could you override `OnActionExecuting()` and process it in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `OnActionExecuting()` your base controller or in an [Action Filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) as suggested by @jrummell. An Action Filter might be the way to go, but you would still need to decorate all of your controllers or create a base controller and decorate that with it.

```
public class PromoActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Promo = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString("Promo");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

[PromoActionFilter]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    ... Some Actions ...
}
```

Comment: You could also handle this in an [Action Filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

Comment: @jrummell yes but then wouldn't I have to add that filter to every action?  (and why do I have to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer, this worked for me)

Comment: If you decorate the controller with the Action Filter, it will apply to all actions.

Comment: @Rohrbs I gotcha but I would still need to set it for every controller. Now, I didn't think I could set it for the base controller and it would apply to all controllers...

Comment: You can add it globally: `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new PromoActionFilter())`

Comment: Perfect. Often there's a better way to do things.