# How to reference "Context" / Controller from Views

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

We're looking to build a mvc4 site with url's such as

- abc.com/site1/home/about
- abc.com/site2/home/about

where each refers to a completely different website/page

now the menu items - home/about/contact/... etc. are also different with user-defined text and links

and the following code in ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml would change from

```
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
```

would change to

```
            <ul id="menu">
                @foreach( var nav_config in dbHelper.getConfig(HttpContext.Current)) 
                       <li>@Html.ActionLink(nav_config.Text, "MyAction", "MyController")</li>
            </ul>
```

Wondering if there's a simpler way to reference the {SiteName} from the view which is a property of the baseController as defined in the link below

or a better way to get the menus from config  db ?

The {SiteName} is implemented using the answer in question - 
[Passing a {sitename} parameter to MVC controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237375/passing-a-sitename-parameter-to-mvc-controller-actions)

Comment: sorry for edit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Send the SiteName in with your ViewModel.  Seems like a good candidate for a base ViewModel, actually, if you always need to know the SiteName.

Comment: Maybe areas is what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the view shouldn't care about what served it. Your parameter is a prime candidate for a base model property.

Have all your models implement the following base class:

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your Layout to use the model `ModelBase`.

Then populate it with whatever you want and wherever you want.