# I want to have username as url parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 3 and I want to have username/id as URL parameter using ASP.NET MVC.

For example I want to have:

```
http://mylink.com/username
```

or

```
http://mylink.com/id
```

to redirect to my `HomeController` action `Profile`.

Is that possible?

I tried to create a new route using

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Profile", // Route name
            "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Profile", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
        );
```

but it is not working.

Thanks

Comment: it most likely not going to work since you need a controller name next to url somethink like http://mylink.com/mycontroller/id

Comment: @COLDTOLD, you do not need to have a controller name. The URL pattern is perfectly legitimate. @salamis, What is the signature of your Profile action method? Does it take `string username` or `int? id`?

Comment: @danludwig I tried the solution given @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235118/asp-net-mvc-route-to-username but it does not work.

Comment: @salamis, see my answer. If you are still having troubles you will need to post more code for anyone to help. Need to see the whole RegisterRoutes method from global.asax as well as your controller class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish the URL pattern you are after. Here is an example that should work:

Route code:

```
// be sure to register your custom route before the default routes
routes.MapRoute(null, // route name is not necessary
    "{username}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Profile", }
);

routes.MapRoute(null,
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Profile(string username)
    {
        // http://mylink.com/myusername should hit this method
    }
}
```

**Response to comment 1**

I prefer not to answer loaded questions without knowing anything about your project or the URL schema you are designing. However I see a problem with it right away.You say you want to have at least 2 URL's:

- http://mylink.com/{username}
- http://mylink.com/About

By definition, this means you cannot have any users with username "About". Otherwise, the system could never know which content to deliver -- the about page, or the profile page for the username "about". In MVC, URL's are case-insensitive.

If you are creating a larger application with more pages, I would suggest you scope the URL for your Profile action. Perhaps something more like this:

- http://mylink.com/profiles/{username}
- http://mylink.com/About

With that said, you can still accomplish the URL pattern you want. But you will have to add several validations to make sure that no users have usernames matching your other routes, and you will have to write more custom routes. So you are really just making more work for yourself. You would have to do something like this in the routes:

```
// more specific routes must be added first

routes.MapRoute(null,
    "About",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "About", }
);

routes.MapRoute(null,
    "{username}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Profile", }
);

routes.MapRoute(null,
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The above routes would match requests for /About to the About action, and all other /somestring requests to the Profile action.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It is working. Is it possible to check the answer posted @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235118/asp-net-mvc-route-to-username and especially the second solution? Can we add those exceptions in case I want to add `http://mylink.com/About` or any other static page? Thanks once again for your help.